# How to check whether two linked lists are equivalent in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, singly-linked-list

This is regarding the Palindrome linked list question (234) on LeetCode. I created a copy of the original linked list and then reversed the original list. Now when I try to check their equivalence using the "==" operator it shows False, even though they have the same value. Why is this happening?

This is the code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next

from copy import deepcopy

class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> bool:
        prev,curr=None,head
        dup=deepcopy(head)
        while curr:
            nxt=curr.next
            curr.next=prev
            prev=curr
            curr=nxt
        print(dup)
        print(prev)
        return dup==prev
```

Result:

```
ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 2, 
next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}}}

ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 2, 
next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}}}

False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `ListNode` doesn't override the `__eq__` (`==`) operator. When a custom class leaves this magic method intact, `dup == prev` is equivalent to `dup is prev`, which compares the identities of the objects, not the values.

For the sake of this question, this means we're actually doing `id(dup) == id(prev)`, which correctly returns `False`, because your `deepcopy` created an entirely different object at a different memory address, so even though they are "value-equal", they aren't the *same* object in memory.

In order to AC this question, you need to implement a method that actually evaluates value-equality for two linked lists. Python has no domain knowledge on what a `ListNode` is, so it (rightfully) keeps its distance.